# ValueError when running a MNIST example on Edge TPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, mnist, google-coral

I try to use my first neural network on a Coral DevBoard by using the MNIST dataset. I have done this by the following steps:

- I use the guide from [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant) to generate a quantized model
- Then I use the `edgetpu_compiler` (version `15.0.340273435`) to generate the model for my edge tpu:

```
Edge TPU Compiler version 15.0.340273435

Model compiled successfully in 219 ms.

Input model: mnist_model_quant.tflite
Input size: 22.45KiB
Output model: mnist_model_quant_edgetpu.tflite
Output size: 96.52KiB
On-chip memory used for caching model parameters: 134.00KiB
On-chip memory remaining for caching model parameters: 7.72MiB
Off-chip memory used for streaming uncached model parameters: 0.00B
Number of Edge TPU subgraphs: 1
Total number of operations: 6
Operation log: mnist_model_quant_edgetpu.log
See the operation log file for individual operation details.
```

- I copy the model on my dev board and generate `Labels.txt`:

```
0 0
...
9 9
```

- I copied the example script from [Coral](https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#3-run-a-model-on-the-edge-tpu)

```
import time
import argparse

from PIL import Image
from pycoral.adapters import classify
from pycoral.adapters import common
from pycoral.utils.dataset import read_label_file
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--model", required = True, help = "File path of .tflite file.")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", required = True, help = "Image to be classified.")
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--labels", help = "File path of labels file.")
    parser.add_argument("-k", "--top_k", type = int, default = 1, help = "Max number of classification results")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type = float, default = 0.0, help = "Classification score threshold")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--count", type = int, default = 5, help = "Number of times to run inference")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    labels = read_label_file(args.labels) if args.labels else {}

    interpreter = make_interpreter(*args.model.split("@"))
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    size = common.input_size(interpreter)
    image = Image.open(args.input).convert("RGB").resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    common.set_input(interpreter, image)

    print("----INFERENCE TIME----")
    print("Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes", "loading the model into Edge TPU memory.")
    for _ in range(args.count):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        interpreter.invoke()
        inference_time = time.perf_counter() - start
        classes = classify.get_classes(interpreter, args.top_k, args.threshold)
        print("%.1fms" % (inference_time * 1000))

    print("-------RESULTS--------")
    for c in classes:
        print("%s: %.5f" % (labels.get(c.id, c.id), c.score))

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

- Download an image from the MNIST dataset
- Run the script with the following command:

```
python3 Classify.py --model mnist_model_quant_edgetpu.tflite --labels Labels.txt --input img_1.jpg
```

And I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Classify.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "Classify.py", line 25, in main
    size = common.input_size(interpreter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/adapters/common.py", line 52, in input_size
    _, height, width, _ = input_details(interpreter, 'shape')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like Coral is expecting your model input to have 4 dimensions `[Batch, Height, Width, Channels]` while your model input has only 3 dimensions.

Comment: So I think I have to modify the training of the model?

Comment: interpreter needs to return 4 values but your model is returning only 3.